# javascript regular expression for DN

Tags: javascript, regex, ldap, dn

I wan a regex to alidate all types of possible DN's

I create one but its not so good.

`/([A-z0-9=]{1}[A-z0-9]{1})*[,??]/` and **some others** by changing it, but in vain.

Posible DN's can be

```
CN=abcd,CN=abcd,O=abcd,C=us
CN=abcd0520,CN=users,O=abcd,C=us
C=us

etc
```

Comment: For what purpose? The LDAP server will tell you if the DN is ill-formed.

Comment: User will enter DN in form. I want to validate it on clientside.

Comment: That seems like part of the problem to me. Users shouldn't know an LDAP DN from a hole in the ground. The user should enter something that uniquely identifies the entry concerned, i.e. a uid, and you should then search for that entry.

Comment: come on, user can administrator.

Comment: `[A-z]` is an error.  If you want to match any uppercase or lowercase ASCII letter, use `[A-Za-z]` or set the case-insensitive flag and use `[A-Z]` or `[a-z]`.  `[A-z]` matches several punctuation characters in addition to the letters.  Also, `{1}` has no effect; all it's doing is cluttering up your regex.

Comment: I repeat, the user, or administrator, should enter a search expression to find the LDAP entry he wants. Alternatively the job of verifying it should be left to the LDAP server. You don't need a solution to this non-problem.

Comment: Cannot it be base DN? If you know about LDAP connectivity then you should admit it. Also please just focus on question i.e.(Regex for DN). Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I created one. Working great.

```
^(\w+[=]{1}\w+)([,{1}]\w+[=]{1}\w+)*$
```

Comment: Does not seem to work with this  `CN=Jeff Smith,OU=Sales,DC=Fabrikam,DC=COM`

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was accepted, because it doesn't come even close to working. LDAP values do not have to consist of only alphanumeric characters and underscores, so `\w+` is woefully insufficient for matching them. The DN in @Smitt's comment doesn't match the regex simply because one of the values contains a space, which is not only permitted but very common. `[^,]+` would be a step in the right direction, but keep in mind that there are several reserved characters, and all of them may be escaped with a \. The regex has to account for that.

Comment: BTW, `[,{1}]` seems doubly superfluous. Why do you need to create a bracketed set for a single character? For that matter, why do you need the `{1}`, when it's followed by something that wouldn't match a comma? You could just replace all that with `,` without any practical change to the regex.

Answer (score 17):

I recently had a need for this, so I created one that perfectly follows the LDAPv3 distinguished name syntax at [RFC-2253](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2253.txt).

### Attribute Type

An attributeType can be expressed 2 ways.  An alphanumeric string that starts with an alpha, validated using:

`[A-Za-z][\w-]*`

Or it can be an OID, validated using:

`\d+(?:\.\d+)*`

So attributeType validates using:

`[A-Za-z][\w-]*|\d+(?:\.\d+)*`

### Attribute Value

An attributeValue can be expressed 3 ways.  A hex string, which is a sequence of hex-pairs with a leading `#`.  A hex string validates using:

`#(?:[\dA-Fa-f]{2})+`

Or an escaped string; each non-special character is expressed "as-is" (validates using `[^,=\+<>#;\\"]`).  Special characters can be expressed with a leading `\` (validates using `\\[,=\+<>#;\\"]`).  Finally any character can be expressed as a hex-pair with a leading `\` (validates using `\\[\dA-Fa-f]{2}`).  An escaped string validates using:

`(?:[^,=\+<>#;\\"]|\\[,=\+<>#;\\"]|\\[\dA-Fa-f]{2})*`

Or a quoted-string;  the value starts and ends with `"`, and can contain any character un-escaped except `\` and `"`.  Additionally, any of the methods from the escaped string above can be used.  A quoted-string validates using:

`"(?:[^\\"]|\\[,=\+<>#;\\"]|\\[\dA-Fa-f]{2})*"`

All combined, an attributeValue validates using:

`#(?:[\dA-Fa-f]{2})+|(?:[^,=\+<>#;\\"]|\\[,=\+<>#;\\"]|\\[\dA-Fa-f]{2})*|"(?:[^\\"]|\\[,=\+<>#;\\"]|\\[\dA-Fa-f]{2})*"`

### Name component

A name-component in BNF is:

```
name-component = attributeTypeAndValue *("+" attributeTypeAndValue)
attributeTypeAndValue = attributeType "=" attributeValue
```

In RegEx is:

`(?#attributeType)=(?#attributeValue)(?:\+(?#attributeType)=(?#attributeValue))*`

Replacing the `(?#attributeType)` and `(?#attributeValue)` placeholders with the values above gives us:

`(?:[A-Za-z][\w-]*|\d+(?:\.\d+)*)=(?:#(?:[\dA-Fa-f]{2})+|(?:[^,=\+<>#;\\"]|\\[,=\+<>#;\\"]|\\[\dA-Fa-f]{2})*|"(?:[^\\"]|\\[,=\+<>#;\\"]|\\[\dA-Fa-f]{2})*")(?:\+(?:[A-Za-z][\w-]*|\d+(?:\.\d+)*)=(?:#(?:[\dA-Fa-f]{2})+|(?:[^,=\+<>#;\\"]|\\[,=\+<>#;\\"]|\\[\dA-Fa-f]{2})*|"(?:[^\\"]|\\[,=\+<>#;\\"]|\\[\dA-Fa-f]{2})*"))*`

Which validates a single name-component.

### Distinguished name

Finally, the BNF for a distinguished name is:

`name-component *("," name-component)`

In RegEx is:

`(?#name-component)(?:,(?#name-component))*`

Replacing the (?#name-component) placeholder with the value above gives us:

`^(?:[A-Za-z][\w-]*|\d+(?:\.\d+)*)=(?:#(?:[\dA-Fa-f]{2})+|(?:[^,=\+<>#;\\"]|\\[,=\+<>#;\\"]|\\[\dA-Fa-f]{2})*|"(?:[^\\"]|\\[,=\+<>#;\\"]|\\[\dA-Fa-f]{2})*")(?:\+(?:[A-Za-z][\w-]*|\d+(?:\.\d+)*)=(?:#(?:[\dA-Fa-f]{2})+|(?:[^,=\+<>#;\\"]|\\[,=\+<>#;\\"]|\\[\dA-Fa-f]{2})*|"(?:[^\\"]|\\[,=\+<>#;\\"]|\\[\dA-Fa-f]{2})*"))*(?:,(?:[A-Za-z][\w-]*|\d+(?:\.\d+)*)=(?:#(?:[\dA-Fa-f]{2})+|(?:[^,=\+<>#;\\"]|\\[,=\+<>#;\\"]|\\[\dA-Fa-f]{2})*|"(?:[^\\"]|\\[,=\+<>#;\\"]|\\[\dA-Fa-f]{2})*")(?:\+(?:[A-Za-z][\w-]*|\d+(?:\.\d+)*)=(?:#(?:[\dA-Fa-f]{2})+|(?:[^,=\+<>#;\\"]|\\[,=\+<>#;\\"]|\\[\dA-Fa-f]{2})*|"(?:[^\\"]|\\[,=\+<>#;\\"]|\\[\dA-Fa-f]{2})*"))*)*$`

[Test it here](https://www.debuggex.com/r/KaZr-UYvut0Wl0Qd)

Comment: this is great! except it doesn't allow for whitespace between things, as mentioned on page 5. I added `\s*` after the comma between name-component, and on either side of the equals signs inside name-component.

Comment: @DuBistKomisch can you elaborate on second part you did to fix? "and on either side of equals signs in named component. Is that just the equal signs separating ()?

Comment: @JMIII yeah, I can't fit the final regex in the comment character limit (otherwise I would have just posted it in the first place), but essentially `)=(` -> `)\s*=\s*(` in four places, in addition to one `,(` -> `,\s*(`.

Comment: If I try with the above regex and pass it to RegExp() with the single quote  then it is giving an error, ideally, it should accept the string regular expression: Error: Nothing to repeat
    at new RegExp (<anonymous>)    at <anonymous>:1:9

Answer (score 2):

This is not only not possible, it will never work, and should not even be attempted. LDAP data (distinguished name in this case) are not strings. A distinguished name has `distinguishedName` syntax, which is not a string, and comparisons must be made with using matching rules defined in the directory server schema. For this reason, regular expressions and native-language comparison, relative value, and equality operations like perl's `~~`, `eq` and `==` and Java's `==` cannot be used with LDAP data - if a programmer attempts this, unexpected results can occur and the code is brittle, fragile, unpredictable, and does not have repeatable characteristics. Language LDAP APIs that do not support matching rules *cannot be used* with LDAP where comparison, equality checks, and relative value ordering comparisons are required.

By way of example, the distinguished names "`dc=example,dc=com`" and "`DC=example,     DC=COM`" are equivalent in every way from an LDAP perspective, but native language equality operators would return `false`.

Comment: With deference to the venerable Terry Gardner on all things LDAP, the string comparison problem he points out is trivial and should be accounted for by any competent coder. Downcasing both sides of the comparison is just one way to solve for the example he gives. I disagree with language like "not possible", "never work", "should not be attempted." His point is well-taken though, DNs are not user-facing and using a RegEx to parse them, well, who was it that said, 'now you have two problems'?

Comment: According to [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366101) a DN name cannot have any leading or trailing space, so your statement (`dc=example,dc=com` and `DC=example,     DC=COM` are equivalent) is false

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Expression:

```
^(?<RDN>(?<Key>(?:\\[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}|\\\[^=\,\\]|[^=\,\\]+)+)\=(?<Value>(?:\\[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}|\\\[^=\,\\]|[^=\,\\]+)+))(?:\s*\,\s*(?<RDN>(?<Key>(?:\\[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}|\\\[^=\,\\]|[^=\,\\]+)+)\=(?<Value>(?:\\[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}|\\\[^=\,\\]|[^=\,\\]+)+)))*$
```

Test:

```
CN=Test User Delete\0ADEL:c1104f63-0389-4d25-8e03-822a5c3616bc,CN=Deleted Objects,DC=test,DC=domain,DC=local
```

The expression is already Regex escaped so to avoid having to repeat all the backslashes in C# make sure you prefix the string with the non-escaped literal @ sign, i.e.

```
var dnExpression = @"...";
```

This will yield four groups, first a copy of the whole string, second a copy of the last RDN, third and fourth the key/value pairs. You can index into each key/value using the Captures collection of each group.

You can also use this to validate a RDN by cutting the expression to the "(?...)" group surrounded by the usual "^...$" to required a whole value (start-end of string).

I've allowed a hex special character escape "\", simple character escape "\" or anything other than ",=\" inside the key/value DN text. I'd guess this expression could be perfected by taking extra time to go through the MSDN AD standard and restrict the allowed characters to match exactly what is or is not allowed. But I believe this is a good start.