# Ldap Domain Name validator

Tags: ldap, validation, domain-name

I want to create a validator for dn of an ldap, I mean that if I get as input a string from user, my regex, program, library (whatever works) can tell me if string inserted is a ldap dn or not, can You help me??

Comment: I found a regex in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289357/javascript-regular-expression-for-dn, could it be a good one?

Comment: my regex: `\\w+[=]{1}\\w+)([,{1}]\\w+[=]{1}\\w+)*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I asked in the wrong place, however (for those who will make a similar search) I post the answer I found from another part: https://serverfault.com/questions/549961/ldap-distinguished-name-validator

Answer (score 0):

LDAP C API has a function for DN parsing that is called `ldap_explode_dn`. There are also many bindings for different languages (PHP, python, etc.). I suggest you consider using this API as a DN validation tool.